# How to import CArrayDataProvider to controller

Tags: php, yii2

Sorry for my stupid question, I'm realy newbie with Yii, but I don'n know how to import `CArrayDataProvider` to my controller class. I've found one way `Yii::import('application.extensions.CArrayDataProvider');` (after this call I got error `Call to undefined method Yii::import()`) but it isn't work for me, because I haven't folder extensions at all in my project (I use yii basic application). Please tell me, how add CArrayDataProvider in correct way.

In my yii 2 basic application folder there no file with name CArrayDataProvider. May be I should add some refference to yii framework from my application? I installed application from archive file.

Comment: The answer is using SqlDataProvider. Very usefull documentation https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-providers.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CArrayDataProvider` is replaced with `ArrayDataProvider` in Yii2. For using it you just need to include it in a file. Put the below in the beginning of your file.

```
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
```

For more details refer to this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider` that Yii uses by default in their Search models. You should look at its [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html).

Comment: It's primitive approach like in CRUD actions generated by gii, unfortunately it's not suitable for me.

Comment: The best approach is use SqlDataProvider and this documentation https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-providers.md is much better.

Comment: Well you use what best suits your needs.